# Unable to understand git branches

Tags: git

I am using git for the first time in my own project.

I have the following branches

1. HorizontalScroll
2. checkout
3. chrome-custom-tabs
4. master

The thing i am not able to understand is that why is my master branch having just one commit and is branching off?

The longest linear branch that I see in the picture below, what branch is it? It's clearly not my master branch. But I expect it to be my master branch.

Also why is my chrome-custom-tabs branch not branching off like the other branches?

[image: This is the image of my git branches]

Comment: What UI is this? The history certainly looks weird (especially the placement of HEAD and that WIP entry in between the history…). Could you show a screenshot of your history using `gitk --all`? I have more trust in that tool ^^

Comment: @poke This is android studio. My main concern is the master branch. The longest linear vertical line should be my master branch. Which is not. Please help me out how to make it my master branch. I don't even understand which branch doe it belong to?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening is you set the default branch to be `chrome-custom-tabs`. Every other branch is created from `chrome-custom-tabs` branch. It is not branching off because you have been working in it since the last merge you made with `HorizontalScroll` and `checkout` branches.

Try creating a new dummy branch (`git checkout -b dummy`) and make some commits in it. You'll see that the `chrome-custom-tabs` has been branched off.

To merge your current branch with master:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git merge chrome-custom-tabs`

Read these articles:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell

Comment: I never set chrome-custom-tabs to default. It was just recently created. The commit that says 'Make the adapter code more...' is where I created the chrome-custom-tabs. I expected that commit to be a part of the master branch. I just want the longest linear vertical line to me my master branch